# How to automatically capture a (system) date change and refresh the page in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a single webpage which has a race results ticker tape moving (like marquee). I have a client side javascript queue (simply an object array) which adds the latest unique results retrieved from the server side (websocket) in every 5 seconds and I add that result to the queue first and from queue, I append it to the end of ticker tape which is working fine.

for example: once a race is finish now, it's result is automatically added to the ticker tape.

My question is, when the date changed in the clock, i want to refresh the page, otherwise the queue still has yesterday's data so they are displayed in the ticker tape. But I want to display only today's data.
So How can I capture the "date changing" event in javascript so I can clear my queue accordingly.
Really appreciate a help in this. I can use javascript or jquery for this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the time until midnight and then set a function to execute to reload the page or do whatever at that time

```
runAtMidnight(window.location.reload);

function runAtMidnight(fn){
    var midnight = new Date();
    midnight.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0);
    var timeUntilMidnight = midnight.getTime() - Date.now();
    setTimeout(fn, timeUntilMidnight);
}
```

Note: this uses the user's local time....

Comment: great, this is a good solution... Please just tell me if it is possible to reload only that particular DIV instead of the refreshing the whole page when the date changed..?

Comment: Whatever function(s) you use to load the data in the div the first time, you can run them again. I would imagine that there is something that ends up populating a `$scope`d value.  You can just rerun the that, it will update the `$scope`d value and angular will handle updating the view.  Don't forget to `$apply` (or if you have `$timeout` in scope (via DI), use that instead of `setTimeout`)